# How can I find numérical intervals of k-means clusters?

Tags: r, k-means, intervals

I'm trying to discretize a numerical variable using Kmeans. 
It worked pretty well but I'm wondering how I can find the intervals in my cluster.

I work with *FactoMineR* to do my kmeans.
I found 3 clusters according to the following graph :
[image]

My point now is to identify the intervals of my numerical variable within the clusters.

Is there any option or method in *FactoMineR* or other package to do it ? 
I can do it manually but as I have to do it for a certain amount of variables, I'd like to found an easy way to identify them.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided data I have used the example from the `kmeans` documentation, which produces two groups for data with two columns x and y. You may `split` the original data by the cluster each row belongs to and then extract data from each group. I am not sure if my example data resembles your data, but in below code I have simply used the difference between `min` value of column x and `max` value of column y as the boundaries of a potential interval (depending on the use case this makes sense or not). Does that help you?

```
data <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(data) <- c("x", "y")

cl <- kmeans(data, 2)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, cluster = cl$cluster))

lapply(split(data,  data$cluster), function(x) {
  min_x <- min(x$x)
  max_y <- max(x$y)
  diff <- max_y-min_x
  c(min_x = min_x , max_y = max_y, diff = diff) 
})

# $`1`
# min_x      max_y       diff 
# -0.6906124  0.5123950  1.2030074 
# 
# $`2`
# min_x     max_y      diff 
# 0.2052112 1.6941800 1.4889688
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. 
I thought of something similar but I did'nt use the `split`.

Comment: As an additional hint you might use `str(cl)` (`cl` from above code example) to check the content of your `kmeans` ouput. Maybe there is more that you can use for your analysis.